# Rollup Q&A: How can arbitrum or optimism update their rollup with an admin key? I thought Smart Contract were immutable?

Tags: smart-contracts, rollup, updates

Question from reddit

> How can Arbitrum or Optimism update their rollup with an admin key? I
> thought SC were immutable?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from whalesniper

> The code of a SC is immutable, but immutable code can still upgrade
> itself, with admin help. It's not that much of a mystery.

Answer from daniel hines

> The code of smart contracts is indeed immutable; however, because they
> are essentially Turing-complete, there are many ways to modify their
> behavior. [Ethereum's guide to upgrading smart contracts is a good
> primer.](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/upgrading/)
>
> It's worth noting that upgrading the smart contract bridge in e.g.
> Arbitrum is controlled by a multisig, and can [update immediately with
> out warning.](https://l2beat.com/scaling/projects/arbitrum#contracts) This part is the enshrined part on Tezos, and controlled
> by the usual governance process.

Response from Nomadic Labs

> The SC code is indeed immutable but there are several layers of code
> interpretation in the rollup infrastructure: the EVM machine that is
> emulated in the rollup can be updated. Again, this depends on the
> configuration of the individual rollup.